# How to find count of all ViewControllers in Xcode Storyboard?

Tags: xcode

I have and old Xcode project with too many ViewControllers in one Storyboard. Is there a shortcut way to know the count of all ViewControllers in a Storyboard? Xcode version is 11.2.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the terminal to run a `grep` command to search some string:

```
grep -r -c --include \*.storyboard sceneID .
```

in form:

```
grep -r -c --include [pattern] [search string] [search path]
```

- `-r` to search recursively
- `-c` to show count
- `--include [pattern]` to search in files that match the given pattern, such as:

  - `--include \*.storyboard` to search all files with `storyboard` extension
  - `--include \Main.storyboard` to search in files named `Main.storyboard` only
- `[search string]` is the string to search for. Example:

  - `sceneID` seems to be a good enough search parameter to locate all the `viewController`s, even those that don't have a class associated
- `[search path]` to specify where to search from. Example:

  - `.` to search from current folder; you should be in the project's base folder for better search results

The output should look like:

> .../Main.storyboard:12

where `12` is the number of scenes in `Main.storyboard`

Comment: @UsamaAzam :) my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not the perfect way but, I've find a work around to get the count on my own as i like to code for Auto Layout. I hope it helps you too.

1. Right click on storyboard -> open as **Source code**
2. search following text in editor = **sceneMemberID="viewController"**

> this will give you search count just like any editor including table and collection view controller as all have the same sceneMemberId, please find
>   attachment to get a clear view.

[image]